# Impala error: AnalysisException: select list expression not produced by aggregation output (missing from GROUP BY clause?):

Tags: sql, group-by, hue, impala

This is my first post. hope i'll be clear :)

I try to run on impala (using Hue) the next query in 2 version.

**Version 1 (group by 1):**

```
SELECT payment_method,
       (CASE WHEN price <= 1000 AND country = 'israel' THEN  (price+50+0.18*price)/count(Distinct payment_token)/100
            WHEN price <= 1000 AND country <> 'israel' THEN (price+50)/count(Distinct payment_token)/100
            WHEN price > 1000  AND country = 'israel' THEN (price+0.05*price+0.18*price)/100
            ELSE (price+0.05*price)/count(Distinct payment_token)/100
        END) as ASP
FROM traffic_db.traffic_parq
WHERE year = 2016 AND month = 1
Group by 1

Error 1: AnalysisException: select list expression not produced by aggregation output (missing from GROUP BY clause?): CASE WHEN price... (rest of case when statment)
```

**Version 2 (group by 1,2):**

```
SELECT payment_method,
       (CASE WHEN price <= 1000 AND country = 'israel' THEN  (price+50+0.18*price)/count(Distinct payment_token)/100
            WHEN price <= 1000 AND country <> 'israel' THEN (price+50)/count(Distinct payment_token)/100
            WHEN price > 1000  AND country = 'israel' THEN (price+0.05*price+0.18*price)/100
            ELSE (price+0.05*price)/count(Distinct payment_token)/100
        END) as ASP
FROM traffic_db.traffic_parq
WHERE year = 2016 AND month = 1
Group by 1,2

Error: AnalysisException: GROUP BY expression must not contain aggregate functions: 2
```

I don't know what happen to be the problem.
NOTE: If i run a `CASE-WHEN` statement with non-calculated values - it works fine (when i group by also by the case-when statement).

Has someone encountered this sort of a problem?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with this query:

```
SELECT payment_method,
       (CASE when ftb = true THEN 'FTB' ELSE 'Repeat' end) as FTB_Repeat,
       (CASE WHEN price <= 1000 AND country = 'israel'
             THEN  SUM(price+50+0.18*price)/count(Distinct pay ment_token)/100
             WHEN price <= 1000 AND country <> 'israel'
             THEN SUM(price+50)/count(Distinct payment_token)/100
             WHEN price > 1000  AND country = 'israel'
             THEN SUM(price+0.05*price+0.18*price)/100
             ELSE SUM(price+0.05*price)/count(Distinct payment_token)/100
        END) as ASP,
       COUNT(*)
FROM traffic_db.traffic_parq
WHERE year = 2016 AND month = 1
Group by 1,2;
```

Is not really the `GROUP BY` clause.  It is the additional columns in the `select` that are not aggregation.  You could fix it with:

```
GROUP BY payment_method, FTB_Repeat, price, count
```

(Note:  I don't know if Impala allows column aliases in the `group by`.)  The key is adding the additional unaggregated columns.

So, that might be the intention of your query.  Or, possibly, you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT payment_method,
       (CASE when ftb = true THEN 'FTB' ELSE 'Repeat' end) as FTB_Repeat,
       SUM(CASE WHEN price <= 1000 AND country = 'israel'
                THEN  (price+50+0.18*price)/count(Distinct payment_token)/100
                WHEN price <= 1000 AND country <> 'israel'
                THEN (price+50)/count(Distinct payment_token)/100
                WHEN price > 1000  AND country = 'israel'
                THEN (price+0.05*price+0.18*price)/100
                ELSE (price+0.05*price)/count(Distinct payment_token)/100
        END) as ASP,
       COUNT(*)
FROM traffic_db.traffic_parq
WHERE year = 2016 AND month = 1
Group by 1, 2;
```

If I had to guess, this is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick answer :)
Unfortunately this is not the issue. Impala does allow aggregate with aliases (Numbers). 

The query i wrote at first was a mistake - This is not the one i try to run. 

I Edited the real query

Comment: @shayms8 . . . You don't understand this answer.  Try re-reading it.

Comment: Hey Gordon. 
I Think i did understand what you meant... its just it isn't the problem :\

I tried to run the queries you wrote with no success.

Did you check out the edit i've done?
I have only 2 columns - payment_method and a calculated column.
Thus - i need to group by only on the first column. Isn't it?

Neither of your answers worked X_X

Tnx again for all your help!

Comment: @shayms8 . . . You really don't get it.  You cannot aggregate by the second alias because it contains aggregate functions (such as `count()`).  You either need to use conditional aggregation (as in the second of my queries) or separate out the columns in the expression that are not being aggregated.  There is something simple that you are missing; somehow you are overcomplicating the issue.

Comment: I do get it. 
I know what Group By means and i know i can't group by aggregate functions.

I tried the next queries:

` SELECT payment_method,
           SUM(CASE WHEN price <= 1000 AND country = 'israel'  THEN  (price+50+0.18*price)/count(Distinct payment_token)/100
                WHEN price <= 1000 AND country <> 'israel' THEN (price+50)/count(Distinct payment_token)/100
                WHEN price > 1000  AND country = 'israel'  THEN (price+0.05*price+0.18*price)/100
                ELSE (price+0.05*price)/count(Distinct payment_token)/100 END) as asp
FROM ....
WHERE ....
Group by 1

Comment: Which means your conditional aggregation. Does not work.
 also tried "regular" Group by:
` SELECT payment_method, 
CASE WHEN price <= 1000 AND country = 'israel' THEN (price+50+0.18*price)/count(Distinct payment_token)/100 WHEN price <= 1000 AND country <> 'israel' THEN (price+50)/count(Distinct payment_token)/100 WHEN price > 1000 AND country = 'israel' THEN (price+0.05*price+0.18*price)/100 ELSE (price+0.05*price)/count(Distinct payment_token)/100 END) as asp 
FROM .... WHERE .... Group by 1